# Access directory on Linux machine from a Windows 7 machine over WAN

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ssh

I want to access a directory

ON a computer with Linux Ubuntu 14.04 installed as OS,

FROM a computer with Windows 7 installed as OS,

IN Windows Explorer.

In case both computers have Linux Ubuntu 14.04 installed, this is as easy setting up a SSH public-private key pair connection and running the command

```
nautilus ssh://user@WAN_ip_address:port_number/directory_to_access
```

, but how is this done with one computer running Windows 7?

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting down votes for this question :S. Anyone care to elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me a [xy problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

IF you can change your mind about using **only Windows Explorer** to browse your files, i would suggest you to download [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php), and access the files through `ssh/scp` protocol

It´s safer than using any file or block related protocol on the internet, with no cryptography, and if you have a `openssh-server` running you don´t need to bother with seting up a VPN to ensure data security.

Comment: It's only a `xy problem` in case I can I change my mind over using only Windows Explorer ;). Either way, your proposed `WinSCP` seems to work just fine. It even offers a file synchronization option I believe.

Answer (score 2):

**In order to access a Windows machine from a Linux machine (from Terminal):**

> 1. Install packages ntfs-3g and cifs-utils (sudo apt-get install or yum install).
> 2. Create a local mount directory, for example /shared .
> 3. Edit your /etc/fstab and add to it something like so: 
>      `\\WIN-IP\share$ /shared  cifs  rw,noauth,suid,username=computer_name\user_name  0 0`
> 4. Save the file and run: `mount -a`
> 5. Browse to /shared and run `ls`

**In order to access a windows machine from an Ubuntu machine (from GUI):**

> 1. From your Ubuntu machine, open Nautilus.
> 2. On the left panel click "Connect to server".
> 3. Under "Server Address" type: `smb://WIN-IP/share`

[image: Connect to Server]
[image: smb://computer_name/share_name]

**In order to access a Linux machine from windows (from Terminal):**

Follow [this official Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!).

One more thing to take into consideration is that over WAN you'll have to open TCP ports 139 and 445 and UDP ports 137-138 in order to allow Samba access.

Comment: No cryptography on internet could be a problem...

Comment: I think I have to agree with `nwildner`. The proposed solutions seem just fine to me over a LAN, but not over the WAN, since `Samba` is not secure, right?

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to use WinSCP (https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) which supports `sftp`, `scp` and other protocols.

Another suggestion is to use Swish SFTP (http://www.swish-sftp.org/) which integrates into Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility I'd advertise, although I'm not usually keen to, is cloud storage. In this case, advantages of could storage are (though not limited to)

- platform-agnostic
- multi-host synchronisation
- documents are accessed through local copies
- limited impact due to offline hosts.

I'd recommend, of course, open source and free software such as [Seafile](https://www.seafile.com/en/home/) or [Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/), both of which can be implemented either at home or on a dedicated server if you wish. Certain cloud services limit the storage space depending upon what you pay for.